# SignalR hub suggestion

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

Is it better working with one **hub** for all the *lifetime* of the app or using a different **hub** for every *feature* of the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many hubs as you need to separate logical modules or funcionalities in your application. It´s completely up to you because performance won´t be affected.

That being said, it´s better if you only create one connection from a client app (ie:javascript) and keep that connection for the whole lifetime.
You still can create `n` number of proxy hubs for a single connection.

Answer (score 0):

As xleon highlighted, I would go with multiple hubs to separate the logic. For example - Sale team would be connected with SaleHub while Marketing team would be connected with MarketingHub.

Of course, you may connect with whatever the Hub is required by using Javascipt.

Here is the excerpt from this [article](http://www.karthikscorner.com/sharepoint/why-signalr/)

```html
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy(‘contosoChatHub’);
contosoChatHubProxy.on(‘addContosoChatMessageToPage’, function(userName, message) {
console.log(userName + ‘ ‘ + message);
});
connection.start()
.done(function(){ console.log(‘Now connected, connection ID=’ + connection.id); })
.fail(function(){ console.log(‘Could not connect’); });
```